# Netbeans SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, netbeans, slf4j

i have a pure java project in netbeans and i get the warning:

`SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings`

Of course i searched for the warning but all answers related to removing duplicate bindings with maven or pom.xml file.
But i have no pom.xml file and neither using maven.

So how can exclude the bindings?

Comment: A complete list of all the jars on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Open project settings in NetBeans and look for duplicate libraries in your classpath.

Comment: I have no duplicate libraries. But i have multiple (different and needed) libs which seems to contain own bindigs. How can i force using only the binding from my main-project?

Comment: There is no way to force it. SLF4J will scan your classpath for bindings, so your only way is to use libraries which are designed to work together, i.e. don't contain the same classes. You can of course repack JAR files and remove the duplicates, but that's a terrible idea - it might not work as expected and is guaranteed to give you a nightmare to maintain.